# Copy most recent file and move to another folder

Tags: vba

Trying to create a VBA that copy the most recent file in source folder to destination folder. The source folder would have files in this format (seen below)..

In this example; I would want it to copy "AFILENAMENAMES_2022-10-20 - (Published On 2022-10-20 10-09-16)" and move to destination folder.

AFILENAMENAMES_2022-10-20 - (Published On 2022-10-20 10-09-16)

AFILENAMENAMES_2022-10-19 - (Published On 2022-10-19 09-04-55)

AFILENAMENAMES_2022-10-18 - (Published On 2022-10-18 09-16-22)

AFILENAMENAMES_2022-10-17 - (Published On 2022-10-17 09-17-49)

```
Sub Open_Most_recent_FILEFROMFOLDER_pathwayExtract()
    Dim SPath As String, sFile As String, theFile As String, psh As String   Dim xMax As Double, sDate As Date, n As Long

SPath = "\Archive\"   
DPath = "\Extract"
     sFile = Dir(SPath & "*.*")   Do While sFile <> ""
    n = InStr(1, sFile, "AFILENAMENAMES_")
    If n > 0 Then
    sDate = Mid(sFile, n + 15, 10)
      If sDate > xMax Then
        theFile = sFile
        xMax = sDate
      End If
    End If
 
    sFile = Dir()   Loop
    If theFile <> "" Then
     recentfilepath = SPath & theFile
     FileCopy recentfilepath, DPath
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? You want to use the date from the filename or from the file info (e.g. _Datecreated_)?

Comment: Attached code. Looked for most recent file name then inserted in the FileCopy application. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: File name for sure

Comment: Code looks good to me. Is it working? If yes, leave it like it is, I don't thinks that it is possible better than this. If no, let us know what the issue is

Comment: Getting permission denied on the copy section. Is there another way?

Comment: @akh275 And have you checked if the path is correct? (maybe a slash is missing)